# Generic, Protocol-based Tree Structure in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I've been looking at some code examples from another language (Haskell & C# to be specific), and I'm having an issue coming up with a Swift equivalent.

From the Haskell definition, we have:

```
data Tr a = Lf a | Br (Tr a) (Tr a)
```

From C#, we have:

```
public abstract class Tr<T> { }

public class Lf<a> : Tr<a> {
    public a contents { get; set; }
}

public class Br<a> : Tr<a> {
    public Tr<a> left { get; set; }
    public Tr<a> right { get; set; }
}
```

So a Tree is either a Leaf with a content of a generic type, or a Branch with a left & right Tree.

I'm bumping up against the type system in Swift, so I'm not sure what the appropriate form should be. I have:

```
protocol Tree {
    associatedtype Element: CustomStringConvertible
}

struct Leaf<LeafElement: CustomStringConvertible>: Tree {
    typealias Element = LeafElement
    let content: Element
}

struct Branch<BranchElement: CustomStringConvertible>: Tree {
    typealias Element = BranchElement
    let left: Tree<Element>
    let right: Tree<Element>
}
```

At this point, the above is many iterations of banging my head against the wall, so it's probably way off at this point. Leaf seems to be fine, but Branch fails with

```
Protocol 'Tree' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
```

And recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: See https://airspeedvelocity.net/2015/07/22/a-persistent-tree-using-indirect-enums-in-swift/ for a generic (but not protocol based) Tree structure using `indirect enum`.

Answer (score 1):

Direct translation from C#:

```
public class Tr<A> {
    private init() {}
}

public class Lf<A> : Tr<A> {
    public var contents: A

    init(contents: A) {
        self.contents = contents
    }
}

public class Br<A> : Tr<A> {
    public var left: Tr<A>
    public var right: Tr<A>

    init(left: Tr<A>, right: Tr<A>) {
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
    }
}

let leaf1 = Lf(contents: 0)
let leaf2 = Lf(contents: 1)
let branch1 = Br(left: leaf1, right: leaf2)
let leaf3 = Lf(contents: 2)
let branch2 = Br(left: leaf3, right: branch1)
```

Using Swift's `inidirect enum`:

```
indirect enum Tr<A> {
    case Lf(A)
    case Br(left: Tr<A>, right: Tr<A>)
}

let leaf1 = Tr.Lf(0)
let leaf2 = Tr.Lf(1)
let branch1 = Tr.Br(left: leaf1, right: leaf2)
let leaf3 = Tr.Lf(2)
let branch2 = Tr.Br(left: leaf3, right: branch1)
```